# AngularJS: Controllers are not registered when loaded with requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I want to load some of my controllers dynamically via requirejs. I see the files are loaded and the `module.controller` line is called correctly. However, the controller is not actually registered within angular and therefore cannot be used (I get an `Argument 'lazyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined` exception).

**app.js**

```
var module = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

**lazy-controller.js**

```
module.controller("lazyCtrl", function() {});
```

**not-lazy-controller.js**

```
module.controller("notLzayCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.loadController = function() {
    require(["lazy-controller.js"],function() {
      $scope.includedPath = "lazyControllerView.html"; // this is bound to an ng-view directive. It will try to uses the controller and eventually throw the "got undefined" exception
    });
  };
});
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: you cannot add controllers at the point angular app is already bootstrapped (manually or automatically via ng-app)

Comment: Oh no! is it possible to add directives after angular has been bootstrapped?

Comment: nope, I don't think any code can be added afterwards

Comment: It is possible, just tricky.

Comment: See: https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the controller, but its contents can be loaded. This isn't exactly "lazy" however.

```
.controller('lazyCtrl', ['$scope', '$injector', function($scope, $injector) {
  require(['lazy-controller.js'], function(lazyCtrl) {              
    $injector.invoke(lazyCtrl, this, {'$scope': $scope});
  });
 }]);
```